# How to select and extract by using exists in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I d like to select customer who has `type=a` and `product=1`

```
customer type product
A       a       1
A       b       1  
A       c       2 
B       b       2
B       b       1 
C       c       1
C       c       1
```

There fore my desired result is like following

```
customer type product
A       a       1
A       b       1  
A       c       2
```

I d like to add selector `product = 1` in following sample.

```
SELECT t1.customer, t1.type ,t1.product
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND t2.type = 'a');
```

As I am entry-level. if someone has opinion, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the additional condition completely obvious? What did you find confusing about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the condition to the subquery:

```
SELECT t1.customer, t1.type, t1.product
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer AND
                    t2.type = 'a' AND
                    t2.product = 1
             );
```

If you only want the customers:

```
select customer
from yourtable
group by customer
having sum(case when type = 'a' and product = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply,I d like to know how I can `select product =1` first, then apply `where exists`.  because `where exists` seems take much time to achieve.. thanks

Comment: @Heisenberg . . . For performance, you want an index on `(customer, type, product)`, but performance is not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is version as per your requirement

```
WITH CTE_yourTable AS
(
SELECT CUSTOMER
FROM yourTable
WHERE 
type = 'a' AND
product = 1)
SELECT t1.customer, t1.type, t1.product
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM CTE_yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer 
             );
```